# Proving that the eigenvectors can't form a basis if...

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a linear operator $T:R^n\rightarrow R^n$ where $Tx=0$ and I want to show that there can't be a basis of $R^n$ that is formed by the eigenvectors .

After showing that $T$ is linear I assumed that $u,v$ are eigenvectors that belong the the eigenvalue $0$, so if I use $T$ on the vectors I get $Tu=Tv=0 \Rightarrow u=v$ by linearity of $T$ ,and this means that $u,v$ are dependent so the eigenvectors can't be a basis.

Is this accurate?

Comment: Well, if $\;T\;$ is the zero operator then it certainly is diagonal...and *any* vector is an eigenvector of the zero operator

Comment: What does that say about the dim(kerT) ?

Comment: We have here that $\;\ker T=\Bbb R^n\;$ , so...

Comment: Can i use the dimension theorem( dimKerT +dimImT=n )here in any way to conclude that they cant be a basis?

Comment: @us You seem to be missing completely what I'm trying to tell you: if $\;Tx=0\;$ for all $\;x\in\Bbb R^n\;$ ,then that is the zero operator and thus  **certainly** there is a basis of eigenvectors of $\;T\;$ ...in fact, **any basis** is a basis of eigenvectors of $\;T\;$ because **any** (non-zero, of course) vector is an eigenvector of the zero operator !

Comment: I understand what you are saying now and i agree ,but whats confusing me is that im supposed to show that there isn't a basis of egienvectors when T is a the zero operator is there a flaw in the problem that is given?

Comment: Yes, there is: $\;Tv=0\cdot v=0\;$ proves any $\;0\neq v\in\Bbb R^n\;$ is an eigenvector of $\;T\;$ . Are you sure that's **exactly** what the problem says?

Comment: The original problem was to prove that when the representation matrix of T is a diagonal matrix having same values in the diagonal that are not zero there exists a basis of egienvectors ,i thought that i was supposed to consider that case when when T is just the zero operator but apparently not,thanks a lot for your help by the way.

Comment: Well, no: the important thing is the diagonal representation, it doesn't matter **for this** whether the elements on the diagonal (which are the operator's eigenvalues) are zero or not.

Comment: @user3133165 You cannot show that $u=v $ as you have written, unless $T $ is injective, which it clearly is not since by assumption $Tx=0$ for all $x $.